# Can't read read-only property even with OneWay mode set

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

ViewModel

```
namespace My.ViewModels
{
    public class ItemViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private ItemModel _model;

        public ItemViewModel(ItemModel model)
        {
            _model = model;
        }

        public string Name { get { return _model.Name; } }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Controls.ItemControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:My.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="421" d:DesignWidth="786"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:ItemViewModel}">
    <Grid Background="White">
        <TextBlock><Run Text="Name:" /> <Run Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue=Name, Mode=OneWay}" /></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Error:

```
A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Name'
```

I'm trying to do DataBinding to a read-only property from my ViewModel.
I've set the Binding Mode to OneWay.. yet it still throws the error above.
I'm out of clues! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only place you're binding to this property? What happens if you comment out that `TextBlock` completely?

Comment: @Taelia, your property "Name" does not have a setter. That is why you get that error when you TwoWay bind. Also, from what I know, TextBlock cannot be edited.

Comment: @dymanoid I.. am both very amazed at your ability to shoot in the dark, and slightly embarrased it was something that simple. Somewhere else in my code I had a leftover reference that I didn't apply Mode=Oneway to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To use OneWay binding your property should has get and set. So in this case, to fix the problem you just add set to your property like this:

```
public string Name { private set; get { return _model.Name; }
```

Comment: I want the underlying class to keep its read-only properties, so I want to use OneWay binding, and not TwoWay binding. Thanks for the effort though!